# Not redirect to login when not authorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core web application and I am decorating a few controller action methods with `Authorize` attribute.

So, when I am not logged in, it doesn't do any redirect and only shows me a blank page for that controller action. I have gone through a couple of tutorials and they talk about Cookie authentication.
Below is my Configure method in Startup.cs.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "MainCookie",
        LoginPath = "/Login",
        AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Forbidden/",
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = false
    });
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "ExternalCookie",
        AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
        AutomaticChallenge = false
    });
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
    {
        ClientId = "*****",
        ClientSecret = "*****",
        SignInScheme = "ExternalCookie"
    });
    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
    {
        SignInScheme = "ExternalCookie",
        AppId = "AppId",
        AppSecret = "AppSecret"
    });
    app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(new LinkedInOptions()
    {
        SignInScheme = "ExternalCookie",
        ClientId = "*****",
        ClientSecret = "*****",
        ProfileScheme = LinkedInDefaults.ProfileLoadFormat.AppDefined
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

My action here,

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("/questions/ask", Name = "askquestions")]
public IActionResult Ask()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're expected to see login page, if the user is not authenticated Since you configured `AutomaticChallenge` property to false, you won't redirect to the login page. This behaviour is by design. More details [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/687)